# WPF Binding from ParentViewModel to child user control not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Left out irrelevant stuff in code snippets (like private member declaration e.g.)

ViewModel:

```
public class LinearGaugeViewModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : GaugeElementViewModel
{
    public double Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML of "Parent" user control:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HorizontalGaugeElementViewModel}">
            <local:HorizontalGaugeElement Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code behind HorizontalGaugeElement

```
public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Value),
    typeof(double),
    typeof(HorizontalGaugeElement));

public double Value
{
    get => (double) GetValue(ValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
}
```

I want the `Value` in `LinearGaugeViewModel` to the dependency property of `HorizontalGaugeElement`.

When I change the value, I can see the setter `LinearGaugeViewModel.Value` getting set and notifying it's listeners.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Yes still, the setting in the dependency property never gets set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: WPF uses ValueProperty and SetValue to change DP values, not setter like `set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);`. implement property chaged callback for DP registration (DependencyProperty.Register has multiple overloads)

Comment: I don't understand what I did wrong/what I need to change. Would you mind to give a brief example in an answer?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback

Comment: OK, that callback fires. But how does that help me? I still am not having the `HorizontalGaugeElement.Value` property set with the new value. PS: I never had to use that callback before by the way.

Comment: if callback fires, then `Value` is updated with *some* value.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. I have a breakpoint in the callback, and in the setter of the property. The callback hits the breakpoint. The setter never hits.

Comment: setter never hits, because WPF uses ValueProperty and SetValue to change DP values. callback hits the breakpoint - that is the change. you can change Value via common property wrapper in code (`someGaugeElement.Value = something;`), and both setter and callback will trigger. callback matters most.

Comment: From which context am I supposed to set that property? The callback is static, the property isn't. I am *binding* to the **object** which contains a dependency property. I'm sorry I really can't make any sense of what you are trying to tell me. Nor do I understand why I need to go through so much effort to get a value set in the DP

Comment: I'm trying to tell that your assumption about  "the setting in the dependency property never gets set." is incorrect, because callback fires. it is static but object and value are known from arguments - `DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e`.

Comment: Nooooooo, so in reality, I am hunting a ghost for the last 30 minutes...... I just checked by outputting the bound property to a textblock instead, and it responds perfectly to the changes.... I'll go for a cup of coffee now. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for helping me realize I'm an idiot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement [property changed callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback) for DP registration

if callback fires, then your assumption about "the setting in the dependency property never gets set." is incorrect.

WPF uses `DependencyObject.SetValue(ValueProperty)` to change DP values from XAML. Setter of common property wrapper (`public double Value`) is not used

Comment: It's funny, now every word makes perfect sense! haha. Thanks again for the help. Great tip (subscribing the callback), will remember that the next time I am running into issues with DPs!

Comment: One more question, what does "Setter of common property wrapper (public double Value) is not used" mean? The code is not even used via reflection then? Because I just tried, I can do whatever I like in the body of the getter/setter. When I throw an exception it never happens. Is there a way to control the getter/setter?

Comment: setter is not used from xaml, but you *can invoke it from code*, e.g: `var element = new HorizontalGaugeElement(); element.Value = 3.14;`. it is for convenience. DP were a new WFP concept in the world of .NET, and wrapper gives sense of familaroty to developers, who worked with WinForms. So it is possible to put some code in it other than `SetValue()`, but I can't think of good reason to do so